# Unit Test django, not work for testing Login Page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-testing

I not understand.
I use the technique since the official doc, but nothing work for me, it's very very boring.

I always the status code 200, even when I make errors myself.
I not understand, I want just execute a test for login page and inscription page.
And when I connected, I want testing  user profile page.

This is my code :

```
class LoginPageTests(TestCase):

def test_login_user(self):
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'doe'})
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
    response = c.get('/profil/')
    print(response.content)
```

same with username and password void I have status code 200.., 
same with any erros :

```
class LoginPageTests(TestCase):

def test_login_user(self):
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/login/', {'DHSJDHSJKD': 'john', 'SJDSJDLKJ': 'doe'})
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
    response = c.get('/profil/')
    print(response.content)
```

I have the status code 200..and response.content not work.
Where is the problem ? I want just.. testing user login and profile page after login

Thanks guys !

Comment: Status Code 200 just means that there was no Error fetching the page.

Comment: Okay I see. But how to make a functional class to try the login user? The documentation does not really help me